# Determining intersection of kernel and range of a linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was posed the following question : If T is a linear operator on vector space V and given that the kernel and range of T are disjoint, ie. they have only the zero vector in their intersection and T composed T, ie. T^2(v)=0, for each vector v in V, I need to show that T(v)=0.

I made several attempts, but I haven't found anything substantial.

Any help is appreciated. But hints are appreciated more than the answer itself. I'd like to try myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the equation $T^2(\vec v)=\vec0$ and rewrite it as $T(T(\vec v))=\vec0$. Now let $\vec u= T(\vec v)$. Your rewritten equation now implies that $T(\vec u)=\vec 0$.

Since you asked for hints, I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: I continued as follows : Since T(u)=0, u belongs to the kernel of T. Also u belongs to image of T, since u=T(v) is an element from the range of T. Thus u belongs in the intersection of kernel and range of T and hence is the zero vector. And hence T(v)=0, since a linear transformation maps 0 to 0. please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. :) And thanks a lot for the hint. It got me thinking.

Comment: Once you know that $\vec u= \vec 0$, you're done, because you can substitute this into your definition of $\vec u$. But yes, that's the idea.